# C# return all table information from a SQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

I am using the following code to return the data from the first row from the first column to my textBox4. How can i modify this to return all data? i assume that it will need to be similar to my previous functions where i identified all three columns with  (ACCNTNUM,DATE,REASON), but i am not sure on how to make this fit.

```
           using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Tester.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ACCNT [ACCNTNUM]";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    textBox4.Text = reader["ACCNTNUM"].ToString();
            }
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: If you are wanting to display all records from a table, I'd look into chaning your UI to display a table with 3 column headers, ACCNTNUM, DATE, REASON, then create a class object (Model) which has those 3 properties and place your SQL query results in a List<T> of the class type holding those 3 columns, then send that back to the UI

Comment: Okay, i will attempt to use a TableLayoutPanel to try to display all the data.

Comment: BTW, once you start making this a little more general, you are going to find that digging values out of data readers by name is tedious (and can be slow).  Consider using a data layer technology (perhaps something like Dapper) to map your queries to objects.

Comment: Noted, @Flydog57. My program currently will not service more than 20 people and should not contain more then ~40 records at once. If i get this running, i may expand out, but for now, my limitations are in my skills alone.

Comment: Also, as a follow up, would the TableLayoutPanel be the best way to display the data, or is there another object i should be using?